# Handle on db not released during unit test global setup

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, nunit-3.0

I'm using NUnit 3 to do a global setup, which creates a local database needed to run several of my service tests, which looks like this:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class FixtureSetup
{
    private MobileServiceClient _client;
    private SyncService _syncService;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void GlobalSetup()
    {
        _client = Substitute.For<MobileServiceClient>(Settings.SyncUrl);
        _syncService = Substitute.For<SyncService>(_client);
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void GlobalTeardown()
    {
        _syncService = null;
        _client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

`Settings.SyncUrl` contains the URL to Azure to which the Azure App Services SDK will by syncing eventually, and is not relevant to this question.

The one-time setup, simply constructs a new instance of the `MobileServiceClient` and passes that instance to my `SyncService` class, to construct the local store, which looks like this:

```
public class SyncService : ISyncService
{
    private readonly IMobileServiceClient _client;

    private MobileServiceSQLiteStore Store { get; }

    public SyncService(IMobileServiceClient client)
    {
        _client = client;

        Store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(Settings.SyncDb);
        Store.DefineTable<User>();

        _client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(Store);
    }

    public async Task<List<TTable>> All<TTable>()
    {
        var table = await _client.GetSyncTable<TTable>().ToListAsync();
        return table;
    }

    public async Task<TTable> Insert<TTable>(TTable table)
    {
        await _client.GetSyncTable<TTable>().InsertAsync(table);
        return table;
    }

    public async Task<List<TTable>> Search<TTable>(Expression<Func<TTable, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var table = await _client.GetSyncTable<TTable>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        return table;
    }
}
```

`Settings.SyncDb` simply points to the name of the db, called `localstorage.db`, and if on a mobile device, will store this in the application's file repository, on Windows or Mac, it will store it under the user's profile folder. Adding this just for reference.

My problem is that the global setup creates the localstorage.db correctly, but by the time the unit test runs, it cannot access the localstorage.db, because it's seemingly still in use by the global setup method.

I thought that reinstantiating the MobileServiceClient in the test class would resolve this, but it does not seem to do so. Is there a way that I can release the handle on the db, before hitting the unit test?

This is not an issue in development, as I can run the unit tests again after the first fail, but VSTS builds fail the test due to this reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? I do not understand the reason for using mocks (`Substitute`) if the intention was to use the actual instances.

Comment: This question is irrelevant, because the SDK does not seem to be testable in general. Need to find a way around the limitation before I can attempt to test the methods implementing the SDK. Thanks anyway

Comment: One should not be testing what you do no own for that very reason. If the SDK is not testable then encapsulate it behind an abstraction you control. That way there is more flexibility to mock dependencies when testing.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, locally it the tests run perfectly, in VSTS build process they don't. For now, I found a way around my problem with mocks, not what I wanted but it tests my implementation, which is what I wanted. Thanks